# How to access Qt::DisplayRole and specify columns in TableView

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qfilesystemmodel

The `QFileSystemModel` has the following `data` function:

```
Variant QFileSystemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    Q_D(const QFileSystemModel);
    if (!index.isValid() || index.model() != this)
        return QVariant();

    switch (role) {
    case Qt::EditRole:
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
        switch (index.column()) {
        case 0: return d->displayName(index);
        case 1: return d->size(index);
        case 2: return d->type(index);
case 3: return d->time(index);
```

I wonder how I can access the `DisplayRole` and specify the column I want in a QML `TableViewColumn`.

I want to use it in

```
TableView {
  model: fileSystemModel
 TableViewColumn {
   role: //what comes here?
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to access that value in a delegate?

Comment: Is it possible to display data from this role without delegate?

Comment: Also how about accessing the different columns?

Comment: What do you know about the index ?, or before what action do you want to obtain that data ?.

Comment: In principle (see edit) I want to be able to specify that a TableViewColumn should display the size of a file. This seems to be column 1 of the Qt::Displayrole

Comment: in QML the idea of ​​row and column should not be used, the views instead use the roles.

Comment: Ok, I understand. However, as you can see in the snippet above, the QFileSystemModel defined the size as column 1 of the Display role. How to display it then? A TableViewColumn with a dummy role and a delegate which accesses the information like in your answer?

Comment: Exactly, that's what you should do, as the example of Qt shows: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols-filesystembrowser-main-cpp.html

Comment: Ok, this is the reason then. I already wondered why they do it like this if the could just use the info already stored in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access within a delegate you have to use `styleData.index` that returns the `QModelIndex` and pass it the value of the role, in this case `Qt::DisplayRole` that according to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) is `0`:

```
view.model.data(styleData.index, 0)
```

---

if you know the row, column and QModelIndex of parent:

```
view.model.data(view.model.index(row, colum, ix_parent), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to reuse the model several times, you could consider sub-classing QFileSystemModel and add a custom role:

```
class FileSystemModel : public QFileSystemModel
{
public:

    explicit FileSystemModel(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QFileSystemModel(parent) {}

    enum Roles {
        FileSizeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1
    };

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        switch (role) {
        case FileSizeRole:
            return QFileSystemModel::data(this->index(index.row(), 1, index.parent()),
                                          Qt::DisplayRole);
        default:
            return QFileSystemModel::data(index, role);
        }
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const
    {
        auto result = QFileSystemModel::roleNames();
        result.insert(FileSizeRole, "fileSize");
        return result;
    }
};
```

This way, you can simply refer to the role by its name:

```
TreeView {
    model: fsModel
    anchors.fill: parent

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "display"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "fileSize"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

QFileSystemModel inherits from QAbstractItemModel, which has a method called roleNames(), that returns a QHash with the names of the default Roles (e.g. DysplayRole, DecorationRole, EditRole etc..) see:https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames. To be accurate, QFileSystemModel defines its own roles on top of the QAbstracItemModel ones. see: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#Roles-enum

So if you didn't define any custom role, then you can simply refer to the display role with it's default name (display) in your QML file . Like this:

```
TableView {
  model: fileSystemModel
 TableViewColumn {
   role: "display"
 }
}
```

That said, if you define custom roles, you have to override that roleNames() method, to give names to the new roles you defined. In that case, in order to keep consistency with the parent class, you should call first QAbstractItemModel::roleNames() method (in your case QFileSystemModel::roleNames()), and then set the new rolenames in the returned QHash. Here is an example for a login item where I defined host, username and password roles:

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> LoginModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int,QByteArray> names = QAbstractItemModel::roleNames();
    names[HostRole] = "host";
    names[UsernameRole] = "username";
    names[PasswordRole] = "password";
    return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use `model.display` or just `display` to get DisplayRole from any model.